# Android pubblication problem with android 12

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, android-12

I've been trying to upload my app to the store for a day now, but it always comes up with the error "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that contains an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filtering, but without the "android:exported" property set. You cannot install this file on Android 12 or later versions. Visit developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported."

I modified my manifest to be compliant, but it still gives error.

what should I do?

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.municipiumapp.municipium"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>


    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="it.bsdsoftware.maggioliwebserver ,com.onesignal,com.halilibo.bettervideoplayer, droidninja.filepicker ,it.bsdsoftware.idlehandler , it.bsdsoftware.documentviewer, it.bsdsoftware.imagelibrary, it.bsdsoftware.maggioliutility, com.google.zxing.client.android" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:exported="false" android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:name="com.municipiumapp.app.Oracle"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
        </provider>



        <!-- Cerchiamo di non usarla più
        <meta-data
            android:name="environment"
            android:value="PRODUCTION" />-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.municipiumapp.noreply"
            android:value="Bg9CnrgD6SUW8s9U" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.BadgeCount"
            android:value="DISABLE" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.municipiumapp.android.API_KEY"
            android:value="AkvFoPUZo4zdDbf7WjazuBTgBLzNuUNkfKyNysUKDt" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.municipiumapp.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.municipiumapp.utils.OnBootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



        <!-- not used for now -->
        <activity android:name="com.municipiumapp.utils.search.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- search hint text -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.municipiumapp.bottomnavigation.NavigationActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="idserver.servizicie.interno.gov.it"
                    android:path="/OpenApp?nextUrl=https://idserver.servizicie.interno.gov.it/idp/Authn/X509&amp;name=conversation&amp;value=e1s2&amp;authnRequestString=a113habi75b3f7jb1f8ih0d39460061&amp;OpText=Inserisci%20le%20ultime%204%20cifre%20del%20PIN%20ricevute%20insieme%20alla%20tua%20Carta%20di%20Identit%C3%A0%20Elettronica%20per%20accedere%20a%20https://www.comune.cremona.it/serviziCIE&amp;imgUrl=https://idserver.servizicie.interno.gov.it/idpimages/cielogo.png"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.municipiumapp.debug_mode.DebugModeAcitivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried changing the manifest in all ways, I even added android:exported="true" everywhere and change it to "false" but nothing happens, it always gives error

Comment: check out "merged manifest" on the bottom, when you open your manifest. Maybe some of your dependencies aren't adding `exported` tag

Comment: A common problem is that `AndroidManifest.xml` does not only contain those entries you define but also those defined by used libraries. If you use outdated libraries this can add activities without exported flag set. Look at the AndroidManifest.xml of your final APK file, e.g. by decompiling it using Jadx or apktool.